# Testing props that are being passed down to child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

so i need help with writing a test for proper prop passing to a child component.

```
beforeEach(() => {
wrapped = shallow(
    <CommentDetail
        author="Sam"
        timeAgo="Today at 4:45 pm"
        content="nice blog post"

    avatar="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/m_kalibry/128.jpg"
    />
);
});

it("renders author's name", () => {
expect(wrapped.find(".author").prop("author")).toEqual("Sam");
});

// snippet from the react file
<a href="/" className="author">
    {author}
</a>
```

It seems pretty similar to what I found in the docs but I'm getting undefined value in the received value in test output.

There's another test that can be written but I'm not really sure if it's properly testing the props:

```
it("renders author's name", () => {
    expect(wrapped.render().find(".author").text()).toContain("Sam");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100%, but try removing your `find` method. The prop should show up on the component itself, rather than whatever element possesses the `.author` class, unless Author is itself a React component, in which case you'd want to `find('Author')`:

```
expect(wrapped.prop("author")).toEqual("Sam");
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. Also the author is a class on the anchor tag. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Why would you pass an anchor tag a string? Is that's what's showing up as the link text? In that case you could try ```wrapped.find('.author').text()```

Comment: Ah, just saw your edit.  Yes, that will definitely test your prop properly, it verifies that it is being transmitted successfully to the text of your link.

Comment: oh ok thanks! So that is how you would test the text value being passed down properly. :)

Comment: If you're using it as the ```innerText``` of an HTML element, you can do the exact same thing with whichever element is displaying it.